# repeating values to next column

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried to solve this in several ways and have read a lot of different posts, but I am still stuck. I have data that is only in column A on Sheet1 as a list of several hundred entries, but is uneven, so sometimes complaint is several lines or has no resolution (or even no complaint.) However, every set of information starts with the word "New Entry". Therefore, I want on Sheet2 starting at column B, it to create a new column each time New Entry is encountered with all the data below it until the next "New Entry" is encountered. Thank you a million times over if you can help.

Data currently:

```
+----+--------------------+
|    |         A          |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | New Entry          |
|  2 | Smith, Joe         |
|  3 | 15362              |
|  4 | 123-456-7890       |
|  5 | Company1           |
|  6 | Complaint          |
|  7 | Resolution         |
+----+--------------------+
|  8 | New Entry          |
|  9 | Doe, Joe           |
| 10 | 15361              |
| 11 | 234-567-8901       |
| 12 | Company2           |
+----+--------------------+
| 13 | New Entry          |
| 14 | Mary, Joe          |
| 15 | 15360              |
| 16 | 123-097-8641       |
| 17 | Company3           |
| 18 | Complaint          |
| 19 | 2nd line complaint |
| 20 | Resolution         |
+----+--------------------+
| 21 | New Entry          |
| 22 | Doe, Jane          |
| 23 | 15366              |
| 24 | 234-567-8910       |
| 25 | Company4           |
| 26 | Complaint          |
| 27 | Resolution         |
+----+--------------------+
```

To:

```
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+
|   |      A       |      B       |         C          |      D       |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 1 | New Entry    | New Entry    | New Entry          | New Entry    |
| 2 | Smith, Joe   | Doe, Joe     | Mary, Joe          | Doe, Jane    |
| 3 | 15362        | 15361        | 15360              | 15366        |
| 4 | 123-456-7890 | 234-567-8901 | 123-097-8641       | 234-567-8910 |
| 5 | Company1     | Company2     | Company3           | Company4     |
| 6 | Complaint    |              | Complaint          | Complaint    |
| 7 | Resolution   |              | 2nd line complaint | Resolution   |
| 8 |              |              | Resolution         |              |
+---+--------------+--------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

Code Attempt: (My attempt was at first by row, so I did the following code, which caused issues since the data is uneven. I thought columns might be better, if New Entry was used to start the new column.)

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim i As Range
    Dim actualRange As Range
    Dim tmpString As String
    Dim dob As Range
    Dim idn As Range
    Dim comp As Range
    Dim dt As Range
    Dim rsn As Range
    Dim rsn2 As Range
    Dim rsn3 As Range

For Each i In Sheet1.Range("A1:A21303")
    i.Replace "Name ", "Name :"
tmpString = i.Value
    If InStr(i.Value, "Name :") > 0 Then
i.Offset(0, 0).Value = Split(tmpString, ":")(0)
i.Offset(1, 0).Value = Split(tmpString, ":")(1)
Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = i.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value
    ElseIf i.Value = "Name" Then
        Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = i.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next i

For Each dob In Sheet1.Range("A1:A21303")
    If dob.Value = "DOB" Then
        Sheet2.Range("B" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = dob.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next dob

For Each idn In Sheet1.Range("A1:A21303")
    If idn.Value = "ID Number" Then
        Sheet2.Range("C" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = idn.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next idn

For Each comp In Sheet1.Range("A1:A21303")
    If comp.Value = "Company" Then
        Sheet2.Range("D" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = comp.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next comp

For Each dt In Sheet1.Range("A1:A21303")
    If dt.Value = "Date/Time" Then
        Sheet2.Range("E" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = dt.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next dt

For Each rsn In Sheet1.Range("A1:A21303")
    If rsn.Value = "Complaint" Then
        Sheet2.Range("F" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rsn.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next rsn

For Each rsn2 In Sheet1.Range("A1:A21303")
    If rsn2.Value = "Complaint" Then
        Sheet2.Range("G" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rsn2.Offset(2, 0).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next rsn2

For Each rsn3 In Sheet1.Range("A1:A21303")
    If rsn3.Value = "Complaint" Then
        Sheet2.Range("H" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rsn3.Offset(3, 0).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next rsn3

End Sub
```

Comment: How have you tried to solve it? Post your attempt(s) please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub DoIt()
Dim nur As Long: nur = 1
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long: c = 1
Dim lROW As Long
With Sheet1
    lROW = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 1 To lROW
        If .Cells(r, 1).Value2 = "New entry" Then
            c = c + 1
            nur = 1
        End If
        Sheet2.Cells(nur, c).Value2 = .Cells(r, 1).Value2
        nur = nur + 1
    Next r
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Almost, but can it not be over the same sheet?

Comment: @Maldred - I tested it and it did work, are you getting an error or what? And OP Israph - yes it's on the same sheet but it was very easy to put the word "Sheet2" in front of the last `.Cells(nur,c).value2...` reference - I have updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Perspective is the key.
What you are trying to achieve is to split and transpose a range.

This solution post each complaint by columns in a new worksheet, it also has the option to post the complaints as a list (by rows).

It combines the `AutoFilter` and `SpecialCells` methods of the `Range` object in order to set a `Range` with one `Area` per complaint.

*Procedure:*

```
Sub Range_Split_And_Transpose()
Const kItem As String = "New Entry"
Dim iNewEntry As Integer, iRows As Integer
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsTrg As Worksheet
Dim rgData As Range, rgArea As Range
Dim aRcrd As Variant, lRcrds As Long, bItms As Byte

    iNewEntry = MsgBox( _
        "Do you want to include the ""New Entry"" line?", _
        vbApplicationModal + vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton2, _
        "Range Split & Transpose")
    If iNewEntry = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

    iRows = MsgBox( _
        "Do you want to post the output as a List (by rows)?", _
        vbApplicationModal + vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton1, _
        "Range Split & Transpose")
    If iRows = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

    Rem Set Objects
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSrc = .Sheets("DATA")
        .Worksheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)                           'Adds Output Worksheet
        Set wsTrg = .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
    End With

    Rem Set Range Data
    With wsSrc
        If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .Cells(1).AutoFilter               'Clears AutoFilter
        Set rgData = .Cells(1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)
    End With

    Rem Split Range Into Areas - One Area per Complaint
    With rgData
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & kItem
        If .Cells(1).Value2 = kItem Then .Rows(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Set rgData = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Rows(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Cells(1).AutoFilter
    End With

    Rem Post New Entry Line
    bItms = 1
    If iNewEntry = vbYes Then
        bItms = 2
        With wsTrg.Cells(1, 1)
            If iRows = vbYes Then
                .Resize(rgData.Areas.Count, 1).Value = kItem
            Else
                .Resize(1, rgData.Areas.Count).Value = kItem
    End If: End With: End If

    Rem Post Output
    lRcrds = 0
    For Each rgArea In rgData.Areas

        Rem Record to Array
        aRcrd = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rgArea.Value2)
        If iRows = vbNo Then aRcrd = rgArea.Value2

        Rem Post Record
        lRcrds = 1 + lRcrds

        If iRows = vbYes Then
            wsTrg.Cells(lRcrds, bItms).Resize(1, rgArea.Rows.Count).Value2 = aRcrd
        Else
            wsTrg.Cells(bItms, lRcrds).Resize(rgArea.Rows.Count, 1).Value2 = aRcrd

    End If:  Next

    wsTrg.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Also, consider using the AddIn listed below, especially if you need to do this often.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm